# Submit two forms together in Ruby On Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are working on performance management project in ruby on rails, We have created two forms, Goal Sheet & Attribute Sheet, we want next button to be shown in Goal Sheet form.

When we click on it,all its data will be saved in the database and display the attribute sheet form & after filling attribute sheet form,when we click on submit button all the data of Goal sheet & Attribute sheet form will together be displayed like an show page,one above another.

Comment: From what i understand you should be looking to do a ajax post to a action in one of your controllers and then return a object from that action then use it to populate the second form. Other wise you should be having a relationship between the two  models and using accepts_nested_attributes_for in one form submit

Comment: Are the two objects related? If so you may want a nested form.

Answer (score 3):

Its important to note that browser can only send a single form at a time as they are synchronous. (see note below about AJAX)

HTML does not allow nested forms by design as it would be overly complex and lead to many ambiguities.

Instead what you can do is create a form which contains the data for several resources.

You may have noted that Rails like most other frameworks use specially formatted NAME attributes to create hashes and arrays from form data.

For example:

```
<input name="user[name]" type="text" value="John Doe">
<input name="user[age]" type="number" value="45">
```

Would give the following params:

```
{
  "user" => {
    "name" => "John Doe",
    "age" => "45"
  }
}
```

Normally when you use `form_for` you bind the form to a single object. Which gives you a single root key in the params.

If you for some reason wanted to submit two objects that are not related you can create the form tag manually and use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

```
<%= form_tag("/something") do %>
  <%= fields_for(@foo) do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :foo_attr %>
  <% end %>
  <%= fields_for(@foo) do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :bar_attr %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
{
  "foo" => {
    "foo_attr" => "some value"
  },
  "bar" => {
    "bar_attr" => "some value"
  }
}
```

But in most cases you want to use [`accepts_nested_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) together with [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) to create/edit *nested records*.

```
class Hotel
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, reject_if: :all_blank?
end

class Room
  belongs_to :hotel
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Rooms</legend>
     <%= fields_for(:rooms) do |r| %>
       <%= f.number_field :number, step: 1 %>
       <%= f.number_field :beds, step: 1 %>
     <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class HotelController

  # GET '/hotels/new'
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    # seeds the form with empty records that the user can fill in.
    3.times { @hotel.rooms.new } 
  end

  # GET '/hotels/:hotel_id/edit'
  def edit
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    3.times { @hotel.rooms.new } 
  end

  # POST '/hotels'
  def create
    @hotel = @hotel.create(hotel_params)
    respond_with(@hotel)
  end

  # PATCH|PUT '/hotels/:hotel_id'
  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.update(hotel_params)
    respond_with(@hotel)
  end

  private

    def hotel_params
      params.require(:hotel)
            .permit(:name, rooms_attributes: [:number, :beds])
    end
end
```

### What about ajax?

Ajax still does not allow you to send multiple forms at once. But it does let you either combine the form input into a single request or send multiple requests which to the user appears to be a single form submission.

If you are building something like a single page application you should consider using AJAX instead of deeply nested `accepts_nested_attributes`. It lets you structure your app better and give the user better immediate feedback.