# Unpermitted parameter: Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

Im building an app where users can publish there Real Estate properties. So I have two tables one that is called **Property** and the other called **Amenity**(for icons likes bathrooms, pool, and etc.) I made the Amenity table separated from the Property table so I can use it with other tables and I have this error **Unpermitted parameter::gym**

So this is my code:

**property.rb model**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner
    has_many :amenities
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :amenities
end
```

**amenity.rb model**

```
class Amenity < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :property
end
```

**properties_controller.rb**

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_owner!

  .
  .
  .

  # POST /properties
  # POST /properties.json
  def create
    @property = current_owner.properties.new(property_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Tu propiedad ha sido creada!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 .
 .
 .

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_property
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:name, :description, :price, amenities_attributes: [:id, :bathroom, :room, :pool, :gym, 
        :kitchen, :terrace, :balcony, :living_room, :garage, :parking_lot, :green_area])
    end
end
```

**amenities migration table**

```
    class CreateAmenities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
      def change
        create_table :amenities do |t|
          t.integer :bathroom
          t.integer :room
          t.integer :pool 
          t.integer :gym
          t.integer :kitchen
          t.integer :terrace
          t.integer :balcony
          t.integer :living_room
          t.integer :garage
          t.integer :parking_lot
          t.integer :green_areas

          t.references :property
          t.timestamps
        end
        add_index :amenities, [:id, :created_at]
      end
    end
```

**properties migration table**

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :price
      t.string :services
      t.string :rules
      t.string :address
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude



      t.references :owner
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :properties, [:id, :rfc, :created_at]
  end
end
```

**Console logs**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GjmTFKS3cQRwgrSnTLFOoWQV/gXdTgST0nf7GOs7ZS2i8wneFqzADeTLUo26UKkA5392nrDKGZpVyav4LWpfjw==", "property"=>{"name"=>"Propiedad1", "description"=>"Propiedad1", "price"=>"120000", "gym"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Property"}
  Owner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "owners".* FROM "owners" WHERE "owners"."id" = ? ORDER BY "owners"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/kensanchez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Unpermitted parameter: :gym
```

As im concerned this has to work fine, but im having some issues understanding it. I will appreciate your help guys! Thanks.

EDIT:

**My web form**

```
<%= form_with(model: property, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% if property.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(property.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this property from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
                <% property.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :name %>
            <%= form.text_field :name %>
        </div>

        .
        .
        .
       <!--Gym attribute from amenities-->
        <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :gym %>
            <%= form.number_field :gym %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <%= form.submit %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This isn't really a sustainable solution. As the list of available amenities grows the amount of columns on the table will just grow. What you want to do is instead to setup a normalization table (amenities) that stores the definitions of the amenities available and a join table (amenity_properties) that creates a many to many association between Property and Amenity.

Comment: sounds interesting what you said, in fact this is what most people advice me to do. Do you have and resource about what are you saying? Like a blog or something where I can deep dive? I will appreciate it

Comment: I don't know. Start with the rails guides on associations maybe? Relational modeling is more of a topic for an entire book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your parameters `"property"=>{"name"=>"Propiedad1", "description"=>"Propiedad1", "price"=>"120000", "gym"=>"1"}` should has the same structure as it is in `property_params`.

The parameter `gym` has to be inside `amenities_attributes`.

Like this: `"property"=>{"name"=>"Propiedad1", "description"=>"Propiedad1", "price"=>"120000", "amenities_attributes" => [{ "gym"=>"1" }]}`.

**UPD**

Check this out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Try to use this piece of code in the form view:

```
<!--Gym attribute from amenities-->
<%= form.fields_for :amenities do |amenities_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= amenities_form.label :gym %>
    <%= amenities_form.number_field :gym %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Makes a huge sense, but how can I accomplish that? I did add nested attributes in my property model, and I did in fact made it a nested attribute in the permit params. 
How can I make that `"gym"=>"1"`make it to the amenities_attributes?

Comment: You need to create a proper web-form. Please add to your question the code of form from the views.

Comment: Oh! Ok, I just added to my post under Edit.

Comment: I made some changes:

1.- I change the `form.fields_for :amenities do |amenities_form|` to  `form.fields_for :amenities_attributes do |amenities_form|`  **why** Because it wasn't showing the gym input.

2.- Now Im facing another error **no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer**
and the rails error highlights this code in the controller:
`@property = current_owner.properties.build(property_params)`

Comment: Yakov, it worked. The only thing that was causing it to not work is that i needed to add: `@property.amenities.build` in my new method inside the **properties_controller.rb**. Thanks for the help man, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This what I am seeing in your **console logs** output

`"property"=>{"name"=>"Propiedad1", "description"=>"Propiedad1", "price"=>"120000", "gym"=>"1"}`

These are params for a **property** and the last value is **"gym"=>"1"**, this is the reason you are getting **unpermitted parameter**.

It should appear under **amenities_attributes** like

`"property"=>{"name"=>"Propiedad1", "description"=>"Propiedad1", "price"=>"120000"}, "amenities_attributes": [{ "gym"=>"1" }] }`

Comment: Hey Gideon, thanks for the reply, it makes a lot of sense to me, but how can I make that the :gym attribute show with in the amenities_attributes? I did in fact implemented the accepts_nested_attributes, so how can I make this possible?

Comment: @kenSanchez I will refer you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573895/submit-two-forms-together-in-ruby-on-rails-4?rq=1), It kind of addresses how you can submit params with **amenities_attributes** included.